# Moving a Shape with SFML C#

Tags: c#, sfml

I'm wanting to easily move a shape around using [SFML.Net](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.Net) bindings.

Do I have to do `shape.Position = new Vector2f(x, y)` all the time?

The [following](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-shape.php) mentions that to build a custom shape with SFML, you have to use the `sf::Shape` class.

A shape is basically a convex polygon, in which each point can have its own position and color. You can also add an automatic outline to a shape, each point having the ability to define its own color for the outline.

It then goes on to mention that like every drawable object in SFML, shape objects inherit the common functions to set their position, rotation, scale, color and blending mode.

```
Polygon.SetColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 200));
Polygon.Move(300, 300);
Polygon.Scale(3, 2);
Polygon.Rotate(45);
```

Unfortunately `Move(), Scale() and Rotate()` do not exist within C# as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SFML.Net the `Transformable` class (from which `Shape` inherits) has the properties `Position`, `Rotation` and `Scale`. Just use the setter/getter methods.

[src/Graphics/Transformable.cs](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.Net/blob/master/src/Graphics/Transformable.cs)

Comment: Which just means setting it to a new Vector every time, right?

Comment: Yes. The .Net binding seems to be outdated. It might be updated soon as a new version of SFML has just been released.